# Coral Dev Board - can't connect with mdt shell

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb

I've followed the following getting-started guide of the Coral Dev Board by Google: [Get started with the Dev Board](https://coral.withgoogle.com/docs/dev-board/get-started/)

then I reached the title "Connect to the board's shell via MDT" but I received the following error message:

```
~$ mdt shell
Connecting to 192.168.1.93 at 192.168.1.93
Key not present on 192.168.1.93 -- pushing

It looks like you're trying to connect to a device that isn't connected
to your workstation via USB and doesn't have the SSH key this MDT generated.
To connect with `mdt shell` you will need to first connect to your device
ONLY via USB.

Cowardly refusing to attempt to push a key to a public machine.
```

Note that I'm using Nvidia Jetson Xaviar as a host computer in my setup. The Dev Board USB-C-OTG port ***is connected*** to the Xaviar with USB-C to USB-A cable. The Xaviar runs Ubuntu 18.04 LTS OS. Plus, the device is successfully detected with `mdt devices` command, and the IP address is correct.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your board is only connected through USB (not WiFi) before using MDT for the first time. You can do this as follows:

1. Connect to you board through the micro USB port using screen:

   ```
   screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200
   ```
2. Log in:

   ```
   Login: mendel
   Password: mendel
   ```
3. Check your active connections:

   ```
   nmcli connection show
   ```

   You should see your network connections listed in the output. Active connections are the ones that have a device associated. For example:

   ```
   NAME        UUID                                    TYPE              DEVICE
   usb0        cee59267-da42-443f-a8ca-cb94bccf1ad9    802-3-ethernet    usb0
   STRAVINSKY  71db4358-29d4-4da3-96d1-f76baf6a8f88    802-11-wireless   wlan0
   ```
4. Deactivate any connections that are not USB. In this case, `wlan0`. To do this, use `nmtui`, select `Activate a connection`, find the network you want to disable, and mark select `<Deactivate>` on it.
5. Use `mdt shell` on your host machine. It should upload the key correctly and log into the device.
6. Now you can activate a WiFi connection on the Coral Dev Board.

Comment: This doesn't work on macOS Catalina. Any ideas how to fix this?